# How can I leave light spotlight on ground making other portion transparent?

Tags: lighting

I know how leave shadow on ground making other portion transparent, but leaving light, I couldn't find.
Thanks.[image]

Comment: Hello :). Could you please explain your problem a bit more?

Comment: Thank you for your responce.

Comment: Thank you for your responce.
I want to use HDRI as background.
I tried to make car headlight picture and show spotlight on the ground.
I took plane as a ground to catch the light spot from spotlight.
I changed settings a lot but I couldn't find good result.

Comment: Hi :). This is possible with the new Blender 3.0 Shadow catcher https://youtu.be/w70dMniat2M